# How to get class with * in jQuery and CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have many elements:

```
<span class="test"></span>
<span class="aaa"></span>
<span class="test-one"></span>
<span class="test-two"></span>
<span class="aaa-one"></span>
<span class="test-two"></span>
```

How can i get with one select all span with name test*?
I can:

```
$('.test, .test-one, .test-two')
```

but maybe is possible to get this with regex?

```
$('.test*')
```

?

in css:

```
 .test, .test-one, .test-two

 .test*
```

Comment: That's the reason why more specific elements should have both general class and then specific class. In your example, ideal solution would be for all test spans to have class 'test'

Answer (score 13):

You're abusing classes, and are looking for multiple classes instead:

```
<span class="test"></span>
<span class="aaa"></span>
<span class="test one"></span>
<span class="test two"></span>
<span class="aaa one"></span>
<span class="test two"></span>
```

Now, `$('.one')` will correctly return the 3rd and 5th element, and `$('.test')` will return all elements except the 2nd and 5th.

Note that you can also use `$('.two.test')` to get the 4th and 6th element.

Comment: +1 for giving the correct answer instead of the one he's looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Use the starts-with selector:

```
$('span[class^="test"]').
```

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: yeah, that's fine until he adds another class to the same element. Then it'll go wrong and it'll be really difficult for him to work out why.

Comment: While it's most certainly a working solution to the current issue, please try to refrain from helping people into more problems with [XY issues](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) like this.

Comment: @Spudley You're absolutely right and Niels answer is the better practice one. It is good to know about this possibility either, and to know that jQuery offers many kinds of selectors.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from the small example whether there's a pattern to the `-one` and `-two` class names.

If there is a pattern, and your idea is to have alternating classes (eg odd and even rows?), then you might want to consider using the `nth-child()` selector. This will allow you to select the relevant elements without needing to reference *any* class names at all.

In this case, you could do something like this:

```
<div class='container'>
  <span class="test"></span>
  <span class="test"></span>
  <span class="aaa"></span>
  <span class="test"></span>
</div>
```

and then the jquery:

```
$('container span:nth-child(odd)')
```

and

```
$('container span:nth-child(even)')
```

See [the jQuery manual for `nth-child`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) for more info.

If this isn't what you're looking for, then I would suggest following @NielsKeurentjes advice and using multiple class names in the relevant elements.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the classes, because a HTML-Tag can have multiple classes at once:

```
<span class="test"></span>
<span class="aaa"></span>
<span class="test testone"></span>
<span class="test testtwo"></span>
<span class="aaa-one"></span>
<span class="test testtwo"></span>
```

If you can't change the HTML, you can do it with javascript (jquery):

```
$('[class]').each(function(){
   var className = $(this).attr("class");
   if("test" == className.substring(0, 4)) //starts with "test"
   {   doSomething();
   }
});
```

*(This code only works, if the tag has not more than one class)*

But this is dirty code because it scans each dom-element which has a class.
If you only want to apply css-Style, the better solution, if you can't change the HTML, is to add all possible classes to the css-File:

```
.test, .test-one, .test-two{
   ...
}
```

...or using the css3-selectors as mentioned in the other answers, but older browsers won't support it.

Comment: Ok, my jquery-code is crap, you shouldn't use it. Didn't know that jquery has a "starts-with"-selector

Answer (score 0):

You can use either

```
$("span[class*='test']"); // element with test anywhere in class attribute
```

or

```
$("span[class^='test']"); // element with test at the start in class attribute
```

note that these will work only if the element has single class.

however you should better use what @Niels have shown.

For a good CSS selector reference : **[Tutorial from net.tutsplus.com](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/)**